# `AND` and `OR` condition together in `Yii` `ActiveRecord` `findAllByAtributes`

Tags: php, yii1.x

I have a controller function which prepare a condition depending upon some column names (created_user_id, status_id, company_id ). The record is fetched from a table `jobs` and if some condition is satisfied, we have to fetch some more rows with specific `job_id`. Example is giving below.

```
(created_user_id = 123 AND status_id = 15 AND company_id = 400 ) OR (job_id IN (18,22,34) )
```

How can i write this condition with `findAllByAttributes` OR using `findAll` ? I tried with `CbCriteria`; but i have no idea how to combine this AND and OR condition together. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `addInCondition`

For Example,

```
$criteria->condition(('created_user_id = 123 AND status_id = 15 AND company_id = 400', 'OR');
$criteria->addInCondition('job_id ', array('18','22','34'));
$relation_models = Relation::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = '(created_user_id = 123 AND status_id = 15 AND company_id = 400) OR (job_id IN (18,22,34)))';
$models = TableName::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Or,

```
$models = TableName::model()->findAll('column=:t4 OR something IN (2,4,6,7)', array(':t4'=>1));
```